# Как отсортировать двумерный/ассоциативный массив на bash?

Tags: массивы, bash, сортировка

Имееся массив такого вида:

```
declare -A ARRAY

ARRAY[0,0]=число
ARRAY[0,1]='строка'
ARRAY[1,0]=число
ARRAY[1,1]='строка'
# ...
ARRAY[$N,0]=число
ARRAY[$N,1]='строка'
```

Нужно отсортировать его по числам (в обратном порядке, но, думаю, это не принципиально) и получить только список строк. То есть при таких данных:

```
[ 1, 'd' ]
[ 4, 'a' ]
[ 2, 'c' ]
[ 3, 'b' ]
```

На выходе должно быть:

```
[ 'a','b','c','d' ]
```

Пока в голову лезет совсем тупое:

```
DATA=""
for(( i = 0; i < $N; i++ )); do
    DATA+="${ARRAY[$i,0]} ${ARRAY[$i,1]}"$'\n'
done
echo "$DATA" | sort -gr | sed -e 's/^[0-9 ]*//g'
```

Но почему-то это не кажется самым лучшим вариантом :)

Comment: уточните, **что именно** вам требуется получить в результате.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, *"получить только список строк"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На чистом `bash` как-то так, но я не уверен, что это лучше.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A ARRAY

ARRAY[0,0]=5
ARRAY[0,1]='строка3'
ARRAY[1,0]=2
ARRAY[1,1]='строка10'
ARRAY[2,0]=12
ARRAY[2,1]='строка8'

declare -a HASH

N=3

for (( i = 0; i < $N; i++ )); do
        HASH[${ARRAY[$i,0]}]=${ARRAY[$i,1]}
done

RES=
for i in ${!HASH[@]}; do
        RES="${HASH[$i]} $RES"
done
echo $RES
```

Никаких `sort`, `sed`, запусков других `bash`, перенаправления потоков не применяется.

На выходе тестового примера:

> строка8 строка3 строка10

Comment: `${!HASH[@]}` — здесь будет не-числовая сортировка. и, например, `10` будет «меньше» `2`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вы об индексе или о числе в строковом варианте? И да, просто запустите. Я сейчас добавлю вывод.

Comment: `${!HASH[@]}` — возвращает отсортированный список индексов. у меня в тестах сортировка происходила не по числовым значениям (потому я отказался от такого подхода). вероятно это происходило из-за того, что в тестовом массиве присутствовали **и** строки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, просто часто не читают документацию внимательно. На самом деле в скрипте неправильно имена даны: `ARRAY` на самом деле hash, а `HASH` -- array. В этом и разница в выводе. Соответственно легко увидеть, что внутреннее представление hash -- это дерево.

Comment: Оно лучше по производительности и отсутствию внешних заисимостей как минимум. Просто не очень наглядно.

Answer (score 1):

подход, в общем-то, единственно возможный: получить значения из нужного «столбца» и их индексы, отсортировать список по этим значениям, значения отбросить, а по индексам получить значения из другого «столбца».

ваш вариант можно разве что немного оптимизировать, поручив «отбрасывание» самой программе *bash* (и тем самым исключив вызов дополнительной программы — *sed*):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A array

array[0,0]=1
array[0,1]='d'
array[1,0]=4
array[1,1]='a'
array[2,0]=2
array[2,1]='c'
array[3,0]=3
array[3,1]='b'
n=3

data=()
while read n garbage; do
  data+=(${array[$n,1]});
done < <(for i in $(seq 0 $n); do
  echo $i ${array[$i,0]};
done | sort -k 2rn)

echo ${data[@]}
```

---

[конструкция](https://stackoverflow.com/a/124349/4827341)

```
while read ... < <(for ... | sort ...)
```

использована вместо «очевидной»

```
for ... | sort ... | while read ...
```

ввиду того, что при использовании «конвейера» (*pipe*, `|`) создаётся новый экземпляр оболочки, и изменение локальной переменной (в данном случае `data`) «не видно» в основном экземпляре оболочки.

Comment: Но здесь вместо `sed` появляется `seq`  :) На самом деле это не так страшно, во всём скрипте есть вещи намного тяжелей (например, `find` по тысячам файлов)... Просто общие принципы и возможные подходы были не совсем понятны.

Comment: ну, если речь про общие принципы, то лучше, конечно, в первую очередь избавиться от псевдо-многомерного массива. и хранить строки в «обыкновенном» массиве: `a[число]="строка"`. манипуляции сразу же значительно упростятся.

Comment: Не выйдет,числа могут быть неуникальными. Тем более что изначально все они `0`, и значения окончательно формируются в процессе всяких манипуляций перед сортировкой. Вот строки - уникальные, их можно использовать как ключи. Но как тогда сортировать по числовым значениям пока не очень задумывался.

Comment: И вдогонку: а `bash` гарантирует сохранение порядка обхода подобного хэша в цикле `for var in ...`? Независимо от того, что именно будет ключом. И как получить элемент, следующий за текущим?

Comment: 1. неуникальность чисел — очень существенный момент, кстати. из-за него решение с промежуточным массивом, предложенное в соседнем ответе, судя по всему, даст вам не совсем то, что ожидается. 2. сортировать — точно так же. 3. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29161460/4827341

Comment: Во, изначально и делал с двумя связаными массивами. Но почему-то это показалось слишком громоздким, решил упаковать :)